# Validator plugin in javascript/jquery which shows messages as Tooltip

Tags: jquery, validation

Can anyone suggest me the validator plugin which shows Validation message as tooltip and we are not submitting form rather we are sending Ajax call to post data. So when User click on Save button, I should be able call validator and that plugin should highlight the field and when user hover mouse on the field, it should display proper messages. Please any one have used such plugin?

Comment: This is not a supermarket!

Answer (score 1):

Try this jQuery plugin [Validation Engine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine).

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Plugin Tasty Form Validation](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/215/jQuery-Plugin-Tasty-Form-Validation)